# Difference between su vs root SSH login for mounting?

Tags: mount, android, root, su

I have a bash script luks that I use in Android for mounting/umounting encrypted devices, that can be called in a terminal emulator with

```
su -c "luks ..."
```

The script works ok for the first part, except at the mounting time, that in the script I do with:

```
busybox mount /dev/mapper/${vol_arg} ${mount_path}
```

Despite the fact that I get exitcode 0 from this command, the device is not mounted. The command line

```
su -c "mount /dev/mapper/${vol_arg} ${mount_path}"
```

does not work either in the terminal emulator yet it shows no error (df does not shows the device). When I try to execute it agan, I get mounting failed: device or resource busy. If I then try

```
 su -c "umount ${mount_path}"
```

I also get cant't umount...: device or resource busy. What's happening?

However, the REALLY strange point here is that, if I SSH to the tablet as root with the same terminal emulator, the command

```
mount /dev/mapper/${vol_arg} ${mount_path}
```

mounts the device normally (??!!). In addition, if I execute the command

```
'luks ...'
```

as SSHd root, it also works perfectly, even mounting the device.

Why does mounting is working if run as SSH root, and not through su -c?

Even more strange is the fact that the su -c thing works fine in Samsung Android 4.1.2, but not in Cyanogenmod 11 (4.4.2)...

Maybe the cyanogenmod people introduced some ugly bug?

Clues?

Thanks!!

L.

Comment: Now this is funny: after mounting through SSH, the root user sees the content of the volume in the `${mount_path}`, as desired, while other users/apps see the previous content of the `${mount_path}`!! It seems that Cyanogenmod mounting routines are broken.

Comment: Not a single answer...?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to CYM 11 M10, and now `su` works fine. No doubt it was a bug. So now I can mount/umount encrypted stuff as I was always able to do.

It seems the problem is solved in the M10 build.